# how to search books by ISBN on Amazon on iphone

Tags: iphone, rest, amazon-web-services

I want to know how to search the books on Amazon using a web URL resulting JSON or xml.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They used to have what was called "the advertising API" that would let you pull book and other listing data, but have since made it less accessible. Nowadays they encourage people to use their widgets rather than coding anything on top of the API.

Poke around http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html
if you're really determined.

Also keep in mind the business model of the API means that your app should directly drive purchases on amazon, anything else is gray area.

Comment: i think this should be valid, poke around here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html